# Woocommerce: Adding Cart weight in header

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add cart weight to header beside the cart. Just the total weight of cart. I've come so far:

```
<tr class="total-weight">
  <?php global $woocommerce; ?>
  <th><?php _e('Total Weight', 'woocommerce'); ?></strong></th>
  <td><span class="amount"><?php
    $total_weight = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;
    $total_weight .= ' '.get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit');
    echo $total_weight;
   ?></span></td>
 </tr>
```

This code outputs the weight of cart but I'm unable to figure out how do I add it in the header.

any help would be greatly appreciate

Comment: Putting it in the header.php file?

Comment: aha, it's not that easy, there are a bunch of files from which cart, navigation are generated in Woocommerece. It's not that simple.

Comment: I'm referring to the header.php file in your theme itself.

Comment: Do you want it inside table as header or out side the table as header ?

Comment: Hi Rohil, I just want to insert it in header, table is not required

Comment: I've found the solution. It's was easy once I found the files

Answer (score 1):

You could do save your code as a function and simply call that function wherever you need the total weight to show up. For example:

```
function display_weight(){
?>
<tr class="total-weight">
  <?php global $woocommerce; ?>
  <th><?php _e('Total Weight', 'woocommerce'); ?></strong></th>
  <td><span class="amount"><?php
    $total_weight = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;
    $total_weight .= ' '.get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit');
    echo $total_weight;
  ?></span></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```